# When I configured the Tomcat server in Intellij Idea, prompted "port is not specified"

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

When I configured the Tomcat server in Intellij Idea, I was unable to save it, and I was prompted "port is not specified"
[The error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI8DE.png)

[The idea version info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaRUQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Error massage from the screenshot comes from Startup/Connection tab, where the port is either not specified or its "0" for Debug mode. See related issue on YouTrack:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146626